# I can't display a Map in a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, maps

I want to show a map with a markers in my `MainActivity` but it doesn't show any map, seems that it doesn't exist when i run the app.

I have a `Fragment` with in my `activity_main` like this:

```
    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapVieww"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp" />
```

And i a `.java` file like this:

```
public class MapViewFragment extends Fragment{

MapView mMapView;
private GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

    mMapView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapVieww);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mMapView.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately

    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
            googleMap = mMap;

            // For showing a move to my location button
            //googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            // For dropping a marker at a point on the Map
            LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker Title").snippet("Marker Description"));

            // For zooming automatically to the location of the marker
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(sydney).zoom(12).build();
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}}
```

I found the info in internet. Anyone knows where is the fault?

Comment: Is there any log messages or error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all remove your try-catch with `MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());` because:

If you are using MapFragment or MapView and have already obtained a (non-null) GoogleMap by calling getMapAsync() on either of these classes and waiting for the onMapReady(GoogleMap map) callback, then you do not need to worry about this class. See the sample application for some examples.
From docs - https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapsInitializer

Second, make `mMapView.getMapAsync(this);` and move your work with map to implementation of `OnMapReadyCallback`

Third: what do you mean about this - `mMapView.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately` why needed?

on which device you try it? virtual or real?